# Sequelize eager Loading check query (ex: it has...?)

Tags: sequelize.js

```
Project.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserProject'});
User.belongsToMany(Project, {through: 'UserProject'});
```

I want to get Projects have user named 'john'

```
        include: [
          {
            model: model.User,
            where: { name: 'john' },
          },
        ],
```

I want result data,

```
[
    name: 'proejectA',
    Users: [
        { name: 'john' }, { name: 'mike' }, { name: 'dude' } ...
    ]
]
```

But it gave to me

```
[
    name: 'proejectA',
    Users: [
        { name: 'john' }
    ]
]
```

I want Projects with Whole Users, have a user named 'john'.

Is it possible query?

Comment: If you are adding where condition (where: { name: 'john' } ) in include it will return users whose name is john

Comment: @Priyank Actually I want Projects has user whoes name is john with whole Users
But It's return just one user whoes name is john.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't achieve that simply**, but there is a way you can do that :

For that you have to define **one more association** with the `alias`, and **one more `include`** :

```
Project.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'UserProject'});
User.belongsToMany(Project, {through: 'UserProject'});
User.belongsToMany(Project, {through: 'UserProject',as: 'projectUsers'}); // <--- HERE

include: [
    {
        model: model.User,
        where: {
            name: 'john'
        }
    },
    {
        model: model.User,
        as : 'projectUsers'
    } 
],
```

This will produce the **result** somwthing like this:

```
[
    name: 'proejectA',
    projectUsers: [
        { name: 'john' }, { name: 'mike' }, { name: 'dude' } ...
    ],
    Users: [
        { name: 'john' }
    ]
]
```